# Mootools video "ended" binding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

I need to migrate a working jQuery script - over to Mootools to meet the requirements of my project.

The working jquery code is:

```
$('#video').bind('ended', function() {
  //Functions on end here.
});
```

I have tried the following with Mootools...

```
document.id('video').addEvent('ended', function () {
    //Functions here
});
```

and

```
document.id('video').addEvent('ended', function () {
    //Functions here
}.bind(this));
```

However to no effect :( Can any one point me in the right direction please?

Thanks!

Comment: you may need to tell mootools event listeners if `ended` is a native event. try `Element.NativeEvents.ended = 2` - see more here: http://www.garrickcheung.com/javascript/mootools-core-element-native-events/

Comment: Still didnt work. Ive actually switched back to using jQuery as it was much much easier to get done what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MooTools does not support HTML5 media tags events. After adding block [written here](http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/2010/03/02/html-5-video-mootools/) You can use:

```
$('myVideo').addEvent('ended', function(){
//Functions here
});
```

Here **myVideo** is an id of tag:

```
<video id="myVideo"></video>
```